# git hub repo linking

Tags: git, github

I am working on a site that I have a GitHub repo setup for. I just launched it, but like an idiot I didn't just pull the repo from GitHub to the new server, instead I did an FTP transfer only to realize my mistake later.

Is there an easy way to link up the server version with the existing git hub repo then do a `dif` and `push` the changes on the server version to the existing GitHub repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead and clone the repo to the other machine. Copy your changes to the working directory of the new clone. Commit and push and you should be back in business. Hope I'm understanding what you did.

Cheers